# How to delete data from user profile in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to remove dns-records that are associated to the user profile via ForeignKey but I am unable to achieve that. How can I delete it?

When I try deleting from the shell `DnsRecord.objects.filter(profile=self.id).delete()` its working OK but when I run the same queryset in the model it is not deleting.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      DnsRecord.objects.filter(profile=self.id).delete()
    except DnsRecord.DoesNotExist:
         pass
   super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And the Model looks like this

```
class DnsRecord(models.Model):

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='dns_records', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    objects = DnsRecordManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['profile', 'name', 'value']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.value}'
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Hey @Debendra no error just passing silently

Comment: The profile is updated but old dns records are not deleted.

Comment: Yes I have DoesNotExist exception is only firing up when the record is not there.

Comment: Just do ....filter(profile_id=self.id).delete() or filter(profile=self).delete()

Comment: Thanks but that is what I have tried and it has not worked.